# Develop a COBOL plugin to validade comments in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, cobol

[image]What it's the best way of validate comments in COBOL in SonarQube?
I want to validate the presence of tag MYTAG in comments in IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                         00010000
   PROGRAM-ID.  ABC00000.                                            00020000
  *@<MYTAG>                                                         00030000
  *@      PROGRAM    : ABC00000                                     00040000
  *@      OBJECTIVE  : MODULO DE ACESSO A XYZ                       00050000
  *@      DATA       : MAIO 2018                                    00060000
  *@      AUTHOR     : JOHN DOE                                     00070000
  *@</MYTAG>                                                        00080000
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                            00090000
  **********************
```

After exploring SSLR COBOL Toolkit, it seems that SSLR COBOL doesn't detect comments as a Node.

Can I validate COBOL comments with SSLR?

Answer (score 1):

SonarCOBOL does not represent comments as nodes of the syntax tree because they can appear in the middle of a node.
Comments are stored on tokens and you get get them by calling `getTrivia` on an instance 
of [`Token`](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/cobol/apidocs/4.3/com/sonar/sslr/api/Token.html).
Each token stores the comments which are located right before the token.

If you want to visit all tokens of a file, your custom rule class should implement [`AstAndTokenVisitor`](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/cobol/apidocs/4.3/com/sonar/sslr/api/AstAndTokenVisitor.html).
You may also check the tokens of a specific node by using the [`getTokens`](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/cobol/apidocs/4.3/com/sonar/sslr/api/AstNode.html#getTokens--) method on `AstNode`.

You should also check the [documentation for writing custom rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+SonarCOBOL) for SonarCOBOL.

Comment: Many thanks Pierre-Yves, for your reply. Very informative. Meanwhile I opted for treating COBOL sources as a regular file and apply a regex to validate MYTAG.